# Fanimation Blitz 56-in DC - Bypass Remote

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan, rewire

first time poster here.

I just bought [this ceiling fan](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Fanimation-Studio-Collection-Blitz-56-in-Black-LED-Indoor-Outdoor-Ceiling-Fan-with-Light-Kit-and-Remote-7-Blade/1000397453) in Lowes. 
The fan I'm replacing was controlled by 2 3-way switches for the light and 1 switch for the fan.

I wanted to keep this setup but unfortunately the fan I just bought relies on the remote control for operating both the lights and fan (speed, dimming, rotation direction, etc)

**Ideally** I would like to bypass the remote completely and continue using my wall switches. Is this possible?
This fan has a DC motor, so I didn't want to mess with the wiring and void the warranty w/o having certain confidence in what I'm doing.

Worst case scenario I'm going to keep the 2 3-way switches to control the ON/OFF of the fan - mainly with the light ON... and use the remote for the fan, which we don't use as often.

I open the motor casing and I'm attaching a picture of the wiring to the remote receiver.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Img1]
[image: Img2]

Comment: looks like you may be able to install another connector with multiple AC power connections, each controlled by a wall switch

Comment: Hi @jsotola. Thanks for the comment! Can you please elaborate on the type of connector you are recommending? Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.